# Cannot trigger requestError interceptor

Tags: aurelia

I would like to check if the token of the user is valid before processing a request, and I am doing this with interceptors.

following is the code:

```
  request: (request: RequestMessage): any => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log('token expires at', this.expiresAt);
      if (this.isTokenExpired()) {
        console.log('token expired');
        throw new Error("{ message: 'Session expired', statusCode: 401 }");
      }

      if (this.accessToken) {
        this.setAuthorizationHeaders(request);
      }
      resolve(request);
    });
  },
  requestError: (error): any => {
    console.log('request error', error);
    throw new Error(`yo ${error}`);
  }
```

However, while I see the error in the console, it seems to never go through `requestError`. 
I have looked at unit tests for the Interceptor method in the source code, but don't see any thing too different from what I am attempting here. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
adding `HttpClient` configuration code:

```
const request = this.httpClient
  .createRequest(url)
  .withBaseUrl(this.baseUrl)
  .withHeader('Accept', 'application/json');

// Interceptor ?
if (withInterceptor) {
  request.withInterceptor(this.interceptor);
}

// Content type
if (contentType) {
  request.withHeader('Content-Type', contentType);
}

// Params
if (params != null) {
  request.withParams(params);
}

// Data
if (data != null) {
  request.withContent(urlEncode ? UrlUtils.encodeQueryData(data) : data);
}

// Method
switch (method) {
  case 'GET':
    request.asGet();
    break;
  case 'POST':
    request.asPost();
    break;
  case 'PUT':
    request.asPut();
    break;
  case 'DELETE':
    request.asDelete();
    break;
}
```

Comment: What does your HttpClient configuration look like?

Comment: I have added the configuration code in the question

Comment: I'm confused as the Aurelia Fetch Client doesn't have a `createRequest` function.

Comment: we are using Aurelia HTTP Client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is from official doc:

`requestError acts as a Promise rejection handler during Request creation and request interceptor execution. It will receive the rejection reason, and can either re-throw, or recover by returning a valid Request.`

You can see that you only enter `requestError` if and only if thre is an error during request creation: malformed headers, invalid configs etc.

Your usage, as posed in this question is perfectly valid, thus no error will be thrown for `requestError` to kick in.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I suspected. I have taken another approach to the problem and it looks satisfying